# Web Based Project Management software with Scrum and Kanban

Tags: web-apps, open-source, project-management

**So as a background of what is going on:**

I am starting up a company in which will be dealing with game development, the problem comes where as many things a start-up is exactly that.  Starting up, and in turn has a lack of revenue at least for now. So any answer that comes along has to be affordable, or free, and if possible have the ability of having iPhone, Android, and Desktop interaction as well... the last three are a bonus, but I'll take web based for now if that is all there is.

I am looking for either Open Source, or other that project management web app that I can **host myself** on my own server, so I can control all aspects of the program and server, and not worry about some third party going out of business and taking their ball home and shut a site down half way though getting a project out the door.

[JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) can be hosted on a computer yes, but a computer, and not just a web server, which means another kettle of worms.

So I am looking for a web server hosted program that can do Project Management, Scrum and Kanban, if at all possible.

I am basically looking for a service that can allow an admin to host, managers to produce the work flow and place jobs for people to do, and people to do the jobs, but at the same time give it a stepping stone upon where they are.  So in English go from something like this:

I give it to a writer he/she then goes through and does their steps.

- Accepted
- First Draft
- First Review
- Second Draft
- Second Review
- Final Draft
- Final Review
- Finished

Then if need be it would be given to someone else as another project such as a programmer, and they would have their own list.

I basically need something that is geared towards concept to final product in Project Management Software that can handle several groups at once. If this makes any sense?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Saying you need a self hosted solution is all you need to do; you don't need to go on for an hour defending that need. In the mean time this is VERY light on any detail about what you want your workflow to look like. Can you give us more detail about your usage needs and a lot less philosophy?

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't want it to be shut down by asking a question that couldn't be answered. I'll change it, and fill in the gaps.

Comment: Also, I don't know what I am really looking for, that is the problem, this is my first endeavor into this world, and I am not sure exactly what I should be looking for as a good program to use... so that is also a reason why I've come here for help. To allow me to understand what is needed...

Comment: Similar Question, my answer would be the same for this question.  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/tools-for-scrum-and-xp-from-the-trenches/1959#1959  ok just realized you want to host your own...Rally does not meet that...

Comment: Which is the issue, I want to host, otherwise there are some great apps out there, I just worry about security...

Comment: I noticed you said JIRA was out of the question because it can't be hosted on a "web server." That begs the question of what you're defining as a "web server" (what's available to you in terms of operating system, executable environments, languages, databases, etc). That will greatly limit that software that can be recommend to you (*e.g.*, you can't run a Rails based app if you don't have a Ruby stack on your server).

Comment: @DavidAntaramian, web server, Apache, PHP/SQL, the basics, with perhaps designed using HTML5, I don't know, hence why I'm asking here, because I'm new to this and I want to be put on the right foot instead of second guessing myself later down the road because the software isn't what I needed...

Comment: Mind you that is a PHP/Apache stack. That is not the exclusive definition of a web server. Also, it requires java, which you can host here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/free-apache-tomcat-hosting-in-the-cloud-for-java-applications-its-called-openshift

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Kanboard](https://kanboard.net/) for three months and I'm very happy with it. Kanboard is an open source project management software that uses the Kanban methodology.

- It requires a web server and PHP. See [all requirements](http://kanboard.net/documentation/requirements)
- It sends [notifications](http://kanboard.net/documentation/notifications) through email.
- There are a lot of [plugins](http://kanboard.net/plugins) available.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this [TeamDeck Project and Team Management](http://codecanyon.net/item/teamdeck-project-and-team-management/12356846) PHP code is quite good and the author promises to add even more features. Now it supports everything for finance, project management, team management, task, Questionnaries and most important the Kanban Board.

That first link also points to [a demo version](http://demo.teamdeck.co/) you can try.

Answer (score -1):

As an Eylean developer I would suggest our software as it uses web server (http web services) that can be deployed on your own environment. Only one drawback is that Eylean is a desktop client. But it covers all your needs and has many more features for rapid project delivery and agile based process. Check it [here](http://www.eylean.com)

Comment: I don't know if I would call your software affordable. You charge a subscription for self hosting and the more users he has, the more expensive it becomes. Granted, to some people, it could be considered affordable, but a subscription for a piece of self hosted software? I hope that includes updates and support.

Comment: Indeed it does include both support and updates, and by support it includes best in class one with free consultations around processes and usage.If you want you can get it at lower price with lower support level. Finally we feel compared to competition this is a well balanced price for the value you get. Finally, it does get cheaper if you pick more licenses, try it yourself: http://www.eylean.com/en/Planning-board-pricing

Answer (score -1):

A software than you can host on your server or you can use on hosted service is Twproject (I work there) (http://twproject.com). It is built on Java and installs almost everywhere in minutes. Moreover, even if not open source, source code is available for free to every customers under NDA.

Twproject is mainly a work management product based on tasks, but it uses heavily issues with Scrumm and Kanban.
At glance I'll try to map you process using issues (but it can be do using a mix of tasks and issues).
You can define your flow, and then move issues from a state to another: says from "Accepted" to "First Draft" and so on.
This can be do easily with a drag&drop on Kanban columns. 
Issues can be moved from a person to another in the same way.
Every change is tracked on the issue history.

What is nice in Twproject is that it give you several tools to do the same job, so that you could find the best fitting process to reach you goals.